# No Enough Space for Gitlab Backup

Tags: backup, gitlab

I have a Gitlab server which I want to back up.
The problem I am facing is that I don't have enough disk space to do that.
What options do I have ?

Comment: Either clear up some space by deleting things, or back up to an alternative storage. You can't magic up storage space from nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You can [backup to S3](https://serverfault.com/questions/764060/how-to-backup-gitlab-to-the-cloud-s3) or [other cloud storage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#uploading-backups-to-a-remote-cloud-storage). But you will most likely have to make space for a single snapshot.